# Mule Http basic authentication - set username in variable

Tags: mule, mule-studio, httplistener

I have implemented HTTP Basic Authentication for my mule flow application.

It listens on HTTP and the URI is http://localhost:8082/login.

```
<flow name="wsGetReport">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="${wsPath}" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger level="INFO" message="## received" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:basic-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
    <flow-ref name="doSubFlow" doc:name="doSubFlow"/>     
    <logger level="INFO" message="## passed security" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:static-resource-handler resourceBase="${app.home}/classes" doc:name="HTTP Static Resource Handler" defaultFile="index.html"/>
</flow>
```

I would retrieve the username typed in the login by the user, and show it in the http Static resource (an html page).

How can I store the username used in authentication?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the user and password of basic auth using `mel` as following and **store** it in a variable:-

```
    <flow name="SpringBasicAuthExample">
       <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/security" doc:name="HTTP"/>
       <logger level="INFO" message="## received" doc:name="Logger"/>
       <http:basic-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>    
       <set-payload value="#[message.inboundProperties.'Authorization']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
       <set-payload value="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String).substring('Basic'.length()).trim()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
       <expression-transformer expression="#[String credentials = new String(org.mule.util.Base64.decode(payload),java.nio.charset.Charset.forName('UTF-8')); String[] values = credentials.split(':',2); flowVars.user= values[0]; flowVars.pass=values[1];]" doc:name="Expression"/>
       <set-payload value="#[['user':flowVars.user,'password':flowVars.pass]]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
       <parse-template location="index.html" doc:name="Parse Template"/>
       <logger level="INFO" message="## passed security" doc:name="Logger"/>
  </flow>
</mule>
```

And at the end you can store the **username** and **password** in a variable and pass the variable in an html file to display the **username** using `parse-template` dynamically:-
**index.html**:-

```
<html>
<body>
<b>UserName: #[flowVars.user]</b>
</body>
</html>
```

Pls note your `index.html` should be there in resource folder. Here once you get the **username** in variable you can store it or pass it anywhere you wish :)

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [BasicAuthenticationFilter.extractAndDecodeHeader()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.java#L224). this is how Spring Framework does it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get username and password from basic auth Authentication as below:

```
<set-session-variable variableName="userInfo" value="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.split(new String(org.mule.util.Base64.decode(message.inboundProperties.'Authorization'.substring('Basic'.length()).trim()), java.nio.charset.Charset.forName('UTF-8')), ':')]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
        <logger message="user name = #[sessionVars.userInfo[0]] ***** password= #[sessionVars.userInfo[1]]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```